# jquery get all classes of an element except those specified

Tags: jquery

I have a div with multiple classes:

```
<div class="box checker">
```

`.box` is manually set but `.checker` is set dynamically. I need to get the class that isn't `.box` by referencing `.box`. What I've tried gives me `undefined`:

```
$('.box form .submit').click(function() {
    var box = $(this).closest('.box').attr('class:not(".box")');
});
```

Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get?

Comment: The class name is just a string.  You can process that string however you want to remove "box" from it.

Comment: I'm trying to get `.checker`

Comment: How is it possible to call on `.box` but not selecting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.box .submit').click(function() {
    var classes = $(this).closest('.box').prop('class').split(' ');
    classes.splice( classes.indexOf('box'), 1 );
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vCpEh/

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will get all the classes applied on the element box and remove the entry box from the resulting array.

```
$('.box').click(function() {
    var classes = $(this).closest('.box').attr('class').split(' ');
    classes.splice(classes.indexOf('box'), 1);    
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var box = $(this).closest('.checker');
if (box.hasClass("box")) {
   //do stuff
} else {
   //other stuff
}
```

Comment: This doesn't allow for dynamically set classes which was my whole problem

Comment: The OP specified: "I need to get the class that isn't `.box` by referencing `.box`", i.e. he wants the other class name on the same element as `.box`.

Comment: May be it does not solve your problem. It doesn't mean you should downvote it, people spend time to help you and you repay by downvote.

Better frame you question to be more understandable.

Comment: FYI @ArvindBhardwaj I didn't downvote you, but I was explaining why the other person did. And downvotes exist for a reason - if the code doesn't work or isn't what the OP asked, it isn't helpful. Thanks for the attempt though.